# Updating a Literal Control Field twice (once in master, another in sub)

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, content-management-system

I am working with an old CMS

The header tags [title] are being declared in a master 
while the sub page.aspx Calls master to output all header html

```
[header]

[pagecontenttemplate]

[footer]
```

the tricky part is this master takes care of SITE wide title tags
while the page content template only takes care of SOME!

What i am trying to Change is 2 types of pages inside pagecontent template.
(I can not change the already declared header that is in sitemaster.cs ) 
** or else other special pages will not have a title tag text.

So Given These, when I comment out the

```
newhead.Text = "my title tag text ";
```

inside sitemaster.cs then the

```
Literal newhead = (Literal)Master.FindControl("newhead");
newhead.Text = "NEW value title tag text";
```

Starts to work in my page template
but if my control is already declared I CAN NOT change this value

am I missing something here?
How do I update this value?

Comment: Your trying to set properties in the masterpage from within your Page right?

Comment: I might be missing the point, but i would suggest that you use usercontrols for the Header & footer sections of your sitemaster, and give each userconrol public propeties that you can set on Page Load in your page.If you want to be able to render your site master accorrding to the page template that you are using, you need to be able to detect what type of page it is at runtime, i dont know anythinga bout your CMS, but you could do this by detecting the layout type for each page.

Comment: @Derek That is kid of the RIGHT way to do it... but the cms is such a mess that this won't be even possible unless way more time is spent into this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that the issue is due to

[site.master] already called and outputs value for pageLoad function

So when [pagetemplate] try to update the field it can not update anymore. which is why it was causing this commenting out the master code would make the pagetemplate code work and not commenting it will cause the pagecontent code to not update at all.

so my solution will have to be just moving the whole title code into every single special
templates...

seems like there is no shortcuts